# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :route-matches of protocol: #'clout.core/Route

Tags: clojure, compojure

I have two files of interest:
**build.boot**

```
(set-env!
 :source-paths #{"src/clj" "src/cljs" "test/clj"}
 :resource-paths #{"html" "target/main.js"}
 :dependencies '[[adzerk/boot-cljs      "0.0-3308-0"]
                 [adzerk/boot-cljs-repl "0.1.10-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [adzerk/boot-reload    "0.3.1"]
                 [adzerk/boot-test "1.0.4"]
                 [cljsjs/hammer "2.0.4-4"]
                 [compojure "1.3.1"]
                 [com.datomic/datomic-pro "0.9.5186"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.5"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0-RC1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-3308"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.346.0-17112a-alpha"]
                 [org.clojure/test.check "0.7.0"]
                 [org.omcljs/om "0.8.8"]
                 [pandeiro/boot-http "0.6.3-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [ring/ring-devel "1.4.0-RC1"]
                 [http-kit "2.1.18"]])

(require
 '[adzerk.boot-cljs      :refer [cljs]]
 '[adzerk.boot-cljs-repl :refer [cljs-repl start-repl]]
 '[adzerk.boot-reload    :refer [reload]]
 '[adzerk.boot-test      :refer [test]]
 '[pandeiro.boot-http    :refer [serve]])

(task-options!
 cljs {:source-map true
       :optimizations :none
       :pretty-print true})

(deftask build
  "Build an uberjar of this project that can be run with java -jar"
  []
  (comp
   (cljs)
   (aot :namespace '#{vidiot.server})
   (pom :project 'vidiot
        :version "0.1.0")
   (uber)
   (jar :main 'vidiot.server)))
```

and **src/clj/vidiot/server.clj**

```
(ns vidiot.server
  (:gen-class)
  (:require
   [compojure.core :refer :all]
   [compojure.route :as route]
   [hiccup.core :refer :all]
   [org.httpkit.server :refer :all]
   [ring.middleware.reload :as reload]
   [ring.util.response :as response]))

(defonce server (atom nil))

(defroutes all-routes

  (GET "/" [] (response/redirect "index.html"))

  (GET "/ws" [request]
       (with-channel request channel
         (on-close
          channel
          (fn [status]
            (println "channel closed: " status)))

         (on-receive
          channel
          (fn [data] ;; echo it back
            (send! channel data)))))

  (route/files "/" {:root "target"})

  (route/not-found (response/response (html [:div#erro "Page Not Found"]))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (run-server all-routes {:port 8080}))
```

Then I,

```
 > boot build
 > java -jar target/vidiot-0.1.0.jar
```

Followed by going to localhost:9090 in my browser, the terminal prints.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :route-matches of protocol: #'clout.core/Route found for class: clout.core.CompiledRoute
    at clojure.core$_cache_protocol_fn.invoke(core_deftype.clj:554)
    at clout.core$eval5590$fn__5591$G__5581__5598.invoke(core.clj:39)
    at compojure.core$if_route$fn__5887.invoke(core.clj:40)
    at compojure.core$if_method$fn__5879.invoke(core.clj:27)
    at compojure.core$routing$fn__5918.invoke(core.clj:127)
    at clojure.core$some.invoke(core.clj:2568)
    at compojure.core$routing.doInvoke(core.clj:127)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:630)
    at compojure.core$routes$fn__5922.invoke(core.clj:132)
    at org.httpkit.server.HttpHandler.run(RingHandler.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can fix this issue by downgrading **:dependencies** in **build.boot** to `[compojure "1.1.6"]`.

So, my question is, why can't I use `[compojure "1.3.4"]` (the most recent version at this writing) when building my uberjar?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your situation. Just failed `boot build` with compojure 1.3.4, however, I retried with compojure 1.1.6 then it's seems fine. I think you can find root cause from diff https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/compare/5791c738b7d643ace70adb53e554b80d48f84e48...master

Comment: Just got the same error with Boot, Compojure 1.3.4 and Clojure 1.7.0.

Comment: stephen, maybe you can accept @thdr's solution about changing the order of boot tasks? I was able to fix this very issue in that way.

Comment: Sure, seems like a pretty goofy thing to just have to randomly arrange boot task, but, a fix is a fix. :)

Comment: i have similar case, except i am using project.clj, and the code is working in dev environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing `aot` task after `uber` fixes the issue.

```
(task-options! pom {:project 'my-project
                    :version "0.1.0"}
               jar {:main 'my-project.core}
               aot {:namespace '#{my-project.core}})

(deftask build []
  (comp (pom)
        (uber)
        (aot)
        (jar)))
```

Comment: I had the same issue and this fixed it for me. Had me scratching my head for at least an hour...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by adding an exclude for the clout folder. It looks like uberjar is unpacking some compiled clout files on top of those compiled from project source. Example from my project:

```
     (comp (cljs :compiler-options {:output-to "js/main.js"})
           (aot :namespace '#{zoondka-maps.server zoondka-maps.handler})
           (pom :project (symbol (:name project))
                :version (:version project))
           (uber :exclude (conj pod/standard-jar-exclusions #".*\.html" #"clout/.*"))
           (jar :file (str (:name project) ".jar")
                :main 'zoondka-maps.server)))
```